# Why is a reference to dagger component unresolved, although this component is generated?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I use Kotlin with Dagger 2. I created an interface `DataComponent` with `@Component` annotation.

I see that `DaggerDataComponent` is generated under `build/generated/source/kapt/[package path]`.

When I try to use `DaggerDataComponent` I get the `Unresolved reference: DaggerDataComponent` compile time error.

Why is the reference to `DaggerDataComponent`unresolved, although `DaggerDataComponent` is generated?

Comment: Did you import it?

Comment: Yes, I imported it

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan There is no problem with the code. Sources are generated. Dagger doesn't report any problem at  compile time. I see generated `DaggerDataComponent`, but Android Studio doesn't. Seems that this is a bug in AS/IDEA. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a related problem on Kotlin [bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17923). And although they report that bug is fixed it is still reproduced.

Adding the following to module level `build.gradle` resolved an issue for me:

```
idea {
  module {
      sourceDirs += file('build/generated/source/kapt/main')
      generatedSourceDirs += file('build/generated/source/kapt/main')
  }
}
```